# No se puede modificar la columna en método persist

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Quiero insertar un registro con Hibernate con el método entityManager.persist(entity);
pero me lanza este error:

```
ERROR http-bio-8081-exec-14 spi.SqlExceptionHelper:146 - **No se puede modificar la columna "CAMPO_TABLA" porque es una columna calculada o es el resultado de un operador UNION.**
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:333)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521)
```

Por qué indica que "No se puede modificar la columna" si yo estoy tratando de insertar un registro?

**Datos:**

- Estoy usando jdk 1.7, Spring 4.3.10.RELEASE y Hibernate 4.3.11.Final
- Cuando ejecuto el INSERT directamente en la BD SQL Server sí puedo insertar un nuevo registro
- El campo que indica el error viene NULO, en todo caso me tendría que salir error al insertar NULO y no lo que sale en el log

Gracias de antemano por las respuestas

Answer (score 0):

El error se debía a que al insertar se estaba tratando de modificar una campo calculado en sql server automáticamente. Para evitar que Hibernate modifique ese campo calculado y dejar que lo haga la base de datos poner lo siguiente en la columna mapeada:

```
@Column(name = "campo_calculado", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Double campoCalculado;
```